# Why doesn't NavLink with inline styling work?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router

I am using NavLink and tachyons.io for inline styling in a React project. I've tried all activeStyle and stuff, but it doesn't work: NavLink stays with a gray border.

```
<div className="f6 f4-m f4-l red fw2 normal-l br-pill ba bg-white hover-bg-red hover-white b--red no-underline pa2 dib">
      <NavLink className="link no-underline hover-white red" exact activeStyle={{backgroundColor: "inherit", border:"none"}}  to="/dumbNavLink" type="submit">
            hell4NavLink
      </NavLink>
</div>
```

Comment: Is `/dumbNavLink` an existing route ? Does it navigates when you click the link ? And why that `type="submit"` ?

Comment: Also can you provide the css that comes with those classes : `"link no-underline hover-white red"`?

Comment: Are you getting any error ?

Comment: Try to adding `!important` for your style.